Error after upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Hello after update ubuntu 22.04 lts to 24.04 lts , when my pc restared i got this error and i can not open ubuntu. Any advice?


I have the same problem. Here is a more detailed description. Dear admins, should I ask this question separately?
When upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS to 24.04 LTS, the error - “Oh no – something went wrong” occurred. Now I tried to start recovery mode. However, I have the feeling that an endless loop is now being rotated at the point shown in the picture. What can I do to fix the error?
Additional note: I cannot open a new terminal with Ctrl+Alt+T at the point where the apparent endless loop is rotated.

i don't want to lose all the data , did you find solution for fixing this problem ?

Here the pic of the endless loop .

No sorry, i do not have a solution ... for this problem. I hope for help

Upgrading from older release of ubuntu is currently bugged, if you can, make a bootable usb drive, then try to install over it / move data from your hdd to somewhere safe if you want a clean reinstall.

Does this answer your question? Why ubuntu doesn't start getting ae_not_found error?

I've had a similar error; my upgrade went wrong and I was unable to load my Ubuntu system any way.
This is what I did to solve it (lets say my Ubuntu partition is /dev/sda1, change it to show yours):

Get a live USB
Launch Ubuntu as "Try it" on the Live USB
Open a terminal

sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev 
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt


Check if it does the trick:

    apt update
    apt upgrade

be patient: In some steps you can wait 10 minutes or more staring at a "82%" progress bar apparently doing nothing, go take a shower.

If you get an error like Temporary failure resolving ‘extras.ubuntu.com’ try adding nameservers like I had to do:

nano /etc/resolv.conf



add a couple of trusted nameservers

nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220



Check if it does the trick this time:

    apt update
    apt install  --fix-broken
    apt upgrade  --fix-missing

be patient: In some steps you can wait 10 minutes or more staring at a "21%" progress bar apparently doing nothing, go prepare yourself a cup of coffee.
More info:
LiveCdRecovery
How to Fix Ubuntu Update Error

After countless syntax errors, I get Processing was halted because there were too many errors.  E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) when running sudo apt update, sudo apt install --fix-broken and sudo apt upgrade --fix-missing. These same errors occurred during the actual upgrade and I fear that if I reboot, it will fail too so I've not done so. After upgrading and without rebooting, Wine and some other applications no longer run either.

I've had this error in the past, usually this can fix it: sudo dpkg --configure -a
Here you can find more info on code(1):[phoenixnap.com]
(https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fix-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-error-code-1)

In safe mode’s command prompt now but running sudo dpkg --configure -a gives the same long list of errors, many of which are syntax issues. I have a .patch file from another forum but no idea how or where to apply it.

You are a saviour!

Fernando Murrieta's answer was a lifesaver for me. I  had tried "apt install --fix-broken" when I could still get to a terminal, but that broke the system so badly, It would not boot and I'd get the "Oh No! Something has gone wrong error".
These commands entered into a terminal via the "Try Ubuntu" from a liveCD:
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev 
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
apt update
apt upgrade

(with "sda1" replaced by the appropriate drive in my system)
worked perfectly.  It did require more than 10 minutes at "99%" complete, so be patient.
My Ubuntu upgrade broke, by the way, on September 11 when there were abundant claims that it is all fixed now, so I'd still beware of upgrading.

duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/1515233/
